# Update only one column using ID in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database

I want to update only one column in my table by ID .

I don't have any error but this don't work, it won't update. I have ID column and 7 more columns.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update table set amount=@kol where ID=@id" , con);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textbox1.Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kol", textbox2.Text );
```

Comment: did you call `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: is table the real name?

Answer (score 0):

Is your table named "table" or is that just for the example here?

Because otherwise you properbly need to change "table" to whatever table your're trying to update. or surround it with [] if it is actually called "table"

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that you have commited your work , if there is no exception then that will be the reason

and if not put setautocommit(true) - java version

you can find it for c#

please check whether table name is correct and the table which you are verifying is correct

please give some other table name than table for good practice

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have con.Open and ExecuteNonQuery and have the username/password and connectionstring right your code will work.

This will work after you change the connectionstring, if not the problem is sql server.

```
private void UpdateTable()
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=pass");
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update YourTable set amount=@kol where ID=@id", con);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kol", textBox2.Text);
                con.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```